# Is there a way to have a execute a method in another view (not the one opened now) through the current one?

Tags: vb.net

I have an application with multiple screens / sub-menus. On each screen is a translate button to swap between English and French, depending on the current selection. The problem is, when I open the main menu in English then open the sub-menu and change the language to French, certain elements of the main menu do not get translated. To fix this, I need to execute a method in the main menu's class through the sub-menu. I can't just copy the method into the sub-menu's class. Is there a way I can call the method from the sub-menu to change elements of the main-menu?

This is the button to change language, located in the sub-menu called wpfUserSearch.xaml.vb. It ideally would have a method call to execute the methods called subLoadComboBoxesToFrench() and subLoadComboBoxesToEnglish() from the screen wpfUser.xaml.vb.

```
Private Sub btnChangeLanguage_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnChangeLanguage.Click
        Try
            If CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.English Then
                CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.French
                Dim newCulture As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("fr-CA")
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture
                gCurrentStrLanguage = "FR"

            ElseIf CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.French Then
                CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.English
                Dim newCulture As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("en-CA")
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture
                gCurrentStrLanguage = "EN"

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

These are the methods that I want the change language button to call. They are in the main menu, called wpfUser.xaml.vb.

```
Public Sub subLoadComboBoxesToFrench()
        comboLanguagePreference.ItemsSource = ActiveLanguages
        comboLanguagePreference.DisplayMemberPath = "Name_French"
        comboLanguagePreference.SelectedValuePath = "Language_Abbr"

        Me.comboUserRole.ItemsSource = ActiveUserRoles
        comboUserRole.DisplayMemberPath = "User_Role_Name_French"
        comboUserRole.SelectedValuePath = "User_Role_ID"
End Sub

Public Sub subLoadComboBoxesToEnglish()
        comboLanguagePreference.ItemsSource = ActiveLanguages
        comboLanguagePreference.DisplayMemberPath = "Name_English"
        comboLanguagePreference.SelectedValuePath = "Language_Abbr"

        Me.comboUserRole.ItemsSource = ActiveUserRoles
        comboUserRole.DisplayMemberPath = "User_Role_Name_English"
        comboUserRole.SelectedValuePath = "User_Role_ID"
    End Sub
```

Comment: You could do this with an event. The sub menu could throw an event and the main menu could catch it and do it's work.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit further? I like the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Put your two Sub from the main menu in shared so you get

```vb
Public Shared Sub subLoadComboBoxesToFrench()
        comboLanguagePreference.ItemsSource = ActiveLanguages
        comboLanguagePreference.DisplayMemberPath = "Name_French"
        comboLanguagePreference.SelectedValuePath = "Language_Abbr"

        Me.comboUserRole.ItemsSource = ActiveUserRoles
        comboUserRole.DisplayMemberPath = "User_Role_Name_French"
        comboUserRole.SelectedValuePath = "User_Role_ID"
End Sub

Public Shared Sub subLoadComboBoxesToEnglish()
        comboLanguagePreference.ItemsSource = ActiveLanguages
        comboLanguagePreference.DisplayMemberPath = "Name_English"
        comboLanguagePreference.SelectedValuePath = "Language_Abbr"

        Me.comboUserRole.ItemsSource = ActiveUserRoles
        comboUserRole.DisplayMemberPath = "User_Role_Name_English"
        comboUserRole.SelectedValuePath = "User_Role_ID"
End Sub
```

Then just call them from the button

```vb
<Your Class Name>.subLoadComboBoxesToEnglish()
<Your Class Nmae>.subLoadComboBoxesToFrench()
```

Comment: While this might work, I think it's better to find a proper place for each method instead of putting them in a shared class.

Comment: It's true, I tried to not modify too much the original code

Comment: In order for this to work, I'll need to make quite a few private variables public, something I'm not sure is a good idea. Variables like ActiveLanguages and ActiveUserRoles.